# How to add image in UITableViewRowAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add image in `UITableView` Swipe style. I tried with Emoji text & its working fine

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
  let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
      print("edit clicked")
  }

  return [editAction]
}
```

But I need image instead of Emoji, meanwhile I tried

```
editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "edit")!)
```

But it's getting duplicate image, I used images in many format like 20*20, 25*25, 50*50 but still duplicating.

How can I add image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewRowAction image for title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421894/uitableviewrowaction-image-for-title)

Comment: I believe it can be a problem with image size you are trying to set. Please, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37452825/4108415) for more info.

Comment: @Jack try mine solution i hope its solve your problem.

Comment: Can you check button and image sizes? Are they equal?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally in **iOS 11**, **SWIFT 4** We can add add image in UITableView's swipe action with help of `UISwipeActionsConfiguration`

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

            let action =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Files", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
                //do stuff
                completionHandler(true)
            })
        action.image = UIImage(named: "apple.png")
        action.backgroundColor = .red
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])

        return configuration
    }
```

[image]

[WWDC video at 28.34](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/)

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration)

Note: I have used 50*50 points apple.png image with 50 `tableview` `row height`

Comment: It's a good example of swift 4 and ios 11.0, but what about less versions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45301272/7576100 As i found in `UITableViewRowAction` which has limited functionality in swift 3, however you can try with image which has a background color

Comment: I have blue image icon with black background. but image is turning to white while displaying. any idea?

Comment: @krutika. This is inbuilt API. You should go with custom swipe.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with my project, so I did a workaround for this.
I think, this is helpful for you.

When I swipe table cell to the left only for image width, it is working fine.

[image]

But when I swipe table cell more than image width, table cell display like this:

[image]

This happen because to add image I use 'backgroundColor' property.

```
copyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bfaCopyIcon.png")!)
```

So to fix this, I increase image width to the same as table width.

*old image* >>>>>>>>>>>>   *new image*

[image] >>>> [image]

this is the new look:

[image]

This is my sample code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let copyButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "") { action, index in

         print("copy button tapped")

    }
    copyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bfaCopyIcon.png")!)


    let accessButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "") { action, index in

       print("Access button tapped")

    }
    accessButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bfaAccess.png")!)


    return [accessButton, copyButton]
}
```

Comment: Where is the code in your solution which shows you have increased width of Image?

Comment: @NileshPol: No need extra code, just replace with increased width of an image

Answer (score 3):

I came across this same problem and discovered a really good pod for this called `SwipeCellKit` that makes it really easy to implement an image into your swipe cell action without the swipe action causing multiple images to show. it also allows for more customization such as different swipe directions.

**Steps:**

1. add pod
2. `import SwipeCellKit`
3. make cell conform to `SwipeTableViewCell`
4. in `cellForRow` function set the cells delegate to self
5. follow the implementation below or via the link

link to pod -> https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        // handle action by updating model with deletion
    }

    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")

    return [deleteAction]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
    var options = SwipeOptions()
    options.expansionStyle = .destructive
    return options
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one way of doing this in **SWIFT 3** -

[image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        //print(cell?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0)//hence we need this height of image in points. make sure your contentview of image is smaller
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title:"       ") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            print("delete clicked")
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:UIImage(named: "delete")!)
        return [deleteAction]
    }
```

We need to make sure our image dimension is matching with cell row height 
Here is my image which i used[image]

Comment: As i found in `UITableViewRowAction` which has limited functionality in swift 3,  however you can try with image which has a background color.

Comment: Then how to change 'backgroundColor' as I needed. I need both backgroundColor with an image.

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun for that case, create custom swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it in `objective-c` and should work in `swift` when translated.

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *deleteString = @"Delete";
    CGFloat tableViewCellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete_icon"];

    CGFloat fittingMultiplier = 0.4f;
    CGFloat iOS8PlusFontSize = 18.0f;
    CGFloat underImageFontSize = 13.0f;
    CGFloat marginHorizontaliOS8Plus = 15.0f;
    CGFloat marginVerticalBetweenTextAndImage = 3.0f;

    float titleMultiplier = fittingMultiplier;

    NSString *titleSpaceString= [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:[deleteString length]*titleMultiplier withString:@"\u3000" startingAtIndex:0];

    UITableViewRowAction *rowAction= [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:titleSpaceString handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        //Do Stuff
    }];

    CGSize frameGuess=CGSizeMake((marginHorizontaliOS8Plus*2)+[titleSpaceString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, tableViewCellHeight) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:iOS8PlusFontSize] } context:nil].size.width, tableViewCellHeight);

    CGSize tripleFrame=CGSizeMake(frameGuess.width*3.0f, frameGuess.height*3.0f);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tripleFrame, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor blueColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, tripleFrame.width, tripleFrame.height));

    CGSize drawnTextSize=[deleteString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, tableViewCellHeight) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:underImageFontSize] } context:nil].size;

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((frameGuess.width/2.0f)-([image size].width/2.0f), (frameGuess.height/2.0f)-[image size].height-(marginVerticalBetweenTextAndImage/2.0f)+2.0f)];

    [deleteString drawInRect:CGRectMake(((frameGuess.width/2.0f)-(drawnTextSize.width/2.0f))*([[UIApplication sharedApplication] userInterfaceLayoutDirection]==UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft ? -1 : 1), (frameGuess.height/2.0f)+(marginVerticalBetweenTextAndImage/2.0f)+2.0f, frameGuess.width, frameGuess.height) withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:underImageFontSize], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor] }];

    [rowAction setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()]];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return @[rowAction];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let write = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "\u{1F58A}") { action, index in
        print("edit button tapped")
    }

    return [write]
}
```

try this used unicode instead icon. this will work