# iOS: Trash Can Delete Button for UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uitableviewrowaction

Is there a way to add this icon to a `UITableViewRowAction` when a `UITableView`'s `UITableViewCell` is swiped right, without setting the `patternImage` of the `UITableViewRowAction`'s background?

i.e. add access this icon:

[image]
,

into the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "", handler: {})

}
```

Comment: I am also looking for the same here ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771778/how-to-add-image-in-uitableviewrowaction

Comment: @Jack Bizarre this isn't built in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but will be possible in iOS 11. Here is a tutorial for implementing these custom actions:

https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/ios-11-swipe-leftright-in-uitableviewcell/