# UITableViewRowAction Limit Size

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created my custom action:

```
public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------
        // MORE Action
        //-------------------------------------------------
        var moreAction = UITableViewRowAction.Create(UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default,
                                                     "        ",
                                                     (_tableView, _indexPath) => ShowMoreAlert(tableView, indexPath));
        moreAction.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(StyleKit.ImageOfList_MoreAction("More"));

        //-------------------------------------------------
        // DELETE Action
        //-------------------------------------------------
        var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction.Create(UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default
                                                       ,"        ",
                                                       (_tableView, _indexPath) => ShowDeleteAlert(tableView, indexPath));
        deleteAction.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(StyleKit.ImageOfList_DeleteAction("Delete"));


        return new UITableViewRowAction[] { deleteAction, moreAction };
    }
```

So, I would like to know how can I do to limit the swipe size, because I have an iusse when the user swipe the row all for the left side, look this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is impossible to control the swipe size.

However , Apple provides another better way to create RowActions After iOS11.

We can override method `GetTrailingSwipeActionsConfiguration` to return `UIContextualAction` list.

`UIContextualAction` has property **BackgroundColor** and **Image** , it is more flexible than before.

Re: [Offical Demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/TableSwipeActions/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my iOS native project. I fix that using image width. Please refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422852/1349787).